# investpy error while running for loop: ConnectionError: ERR#0015: error 406, try again later

Tags: python

```
ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-448d9ab61699> in <module>()
----> 1 bgre = inv.stocks.get_stock_information(stock="BGRE", country="India" )

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/investpy/stocks.py in get_stock_information(stock, country, as_json)
   1097 
   1098     if req.status_code != 200:
-> 1099         raise ConnectionError("ERR#0015: error " + str(req.status_code) + ", try again later.")
   1100 
   1101     root_ = fromstring(req.text)

ConnectionError: ERR#0015: error 406, try again later.
```

It used to get executed without any error but now I am experiencing above error .Can someone please explain what this error type is and what should i do in this case to execute the code without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406), the error 406 indicates that

> [...] the server cannot produce a response matching the list of acceptable values defined in the request's proactive content negotiation headers, and that the server is unwilling to supply a default representation.

Accordingly to the [Github of Investpy](https://github.com/alvarobartt/investpy/issues/275#issuecomment-766945562), although, this error is due to the limit of requests that the site has.

> I think you need to wait before sending more requests as Investing.com limits you for some hours, so before sending those requests make sure that you can access https://www.investing.com/equities/ without any problem. Otherwise the only solution is to wait  and next time try to wait more time between each request as Investing.com has some sever limitations regarding the requests to their stocks/equities functionality...